# Moving origin back to original position

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, ibaction

Today, I am trying to get a view to return to its default origin after a cancel. I am using two VCs to do this. One is a footer controller in a tableview, and the other is a modal view, which is presented after the first animation. Whenever I try to go back from the modal view, the origin is still the same one after I did the first animation. Here is the code I am using:

```
 Footer:

    -(IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
      self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-368,320,400);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.tdModal2 = [[TDSemiModalViewController2 alloc]init];


        //    [self.view addSubview:test.view];

        [self presentSemiModalViewController2:self.tdModal2];
}

-(void)moveBack{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,368,320,400);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And in the modal view:

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
     [self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];
    FooterViewController *foot = [[FooterViewController alloc]init];
    self.footer = foot;
 //   self.footer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,35,320,400);
    [self.footer moveBack];

}
```

Comment: I think that your code is wrong, you are creating a new FooterViewController in the cancel method, but you are not assigning to it any view; or if it is assigned automatically then it will be created from the origin of course as if it was a new one; it's not the same footer.view that you animated before.

Comment: Also, using [UIView beginAnimations] is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Comment: @htafoya hmm. Most of the examples I've seen have used that. Also, do you have a 'solid' solution for the problem stated?

Comment: Let me try to understand, you click a button that hides (or moves) the footer and opens a modal. After you click cancel on the modal then the footer should return to its original position. Is that correct I will post as answer what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the following recommendations, they may be good for you.

**Note 1, AffineTransform**

If the translation is always to the same point and always with the same measure, I'd recommend using `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(<#CGFloat tx#>, <#CGFloat ty#>)` instead of modifying the view's frame. This method specifies how much x and y points will the view move.

In that way, returning the view to the original position is as simple as doing `view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity.`

Both of these inside their respective animation block of course.

**Note 2, Using CGPoint to move the origin**

If you just move the origin of the view then the recommendation is to make:

```
CGRect hiddenFrame = self.view.frame;
hiddenFrame.origin.y -= 736;
self.view.frame = hiddenFrame;
```

or

```
CGRect hiddenFrame = self.view.frame;
hiddenFrame.origin.y = -368;
self.view.frame = hiddenFrame;
```

or

```
CGRect hiddenFrame = self.view.frame;
hiddenFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,-368);
self.view.frame = hiddenFrame;
```

The same for the move back. It's more code but it's more understandable.

**Note 3, UIView animation block**

You should use the new blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.25 animations: ^(void) {
        //animation block
}];
```

There are other blocks with more methods as delay, completion blocks, etc.

**Option, Delegate or reference passing**

When you create your modal controller, pass the reference of the current controller:

```
self.tdModal2 = [[TDSemiModalViewController2 alloc]init];
self.tdModal2.delegate = self;
```

You should declare that property in the **TDSemiModalViewController2.h**. Either by declaring the `@class FooterViewController` to avoid crossed imports; by making a protocol and declaring the property as `id<myModalProtocol>`, **FooterViewController** should then implement the protocol with the method `moveBack`; Or just declare the property as **id** and call `[self.delegate performSelector: @selector(moveBack)]`.

Then in the cancel method, simply do:

```
[self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];
[self.delegate moveBack] //or performSelector.. in the third option case
```